# toDataURL(), from the Web onto my Computer

Tags: javascript, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

I'm interested in using the canvas method `toDataURL()` to grab frames from the canvas and eventually turn it into a movie.

I can easily create an array of frames using this method. The question is, how do I get those frames onto my hard drive so that I can work with them?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through Javascript alone.  Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript):

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-related actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files.

However, there are other ways to accomplish your goal.  If you are using HTML5, for example, you can use the File APIs.  Check out a tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Good Luck!